# Redirect "Add to Cart" from Category page to CMS page

Tags: redirect, addtocart

On my category page, if the user clicks "Add to Cart", then I want to add that product to their cart and then redirect to a CMS page.

I've seen the other solutions available, but none of them seem to address the situation from the *category* view - only from the product page itself.

Currently, the Add to Cart button uses `onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $addCartUrl; ?>')"` where `$addCartUrl = $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product);`

This `addCartUrl` redirects automatically to `/checkout/cart`.

**How can I redefine the redirect for category pages only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the checkout/cart redirection after add to cart in admin panel.

> System » Configuration » Checkout » Shopping Cart » "After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart"

If you want to redirect specific page after add to cart .you can use following event

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
```

Comment: The above comment was before the post was edited. Current answer works well.

Comment: This my simple cms page, add to cart not working could you pls help me solve this issue -> code https://justpaste.it/40ryd